# Improved CSS syntax highlighting in vim

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting

The CSS syntax highlighting in vim is not entirely optimal. For example:

```
div.special_class
```

stops the highlighting at the `_`.

Is there an improved highlighter that doesn't bite on an underscore?

Update:
I'm using VIM - Vi IMproved 7.1 (2007 May 12, compiled Jun 17 2008 15:22:40)

and the header of my css.vim is:

```
" Vim syntax file
" Language:     Cascading Style Sheets
" Maintainer:   Claudio Fleiner <claudio@fleiner.com>
" URL:          http://www.fleiner.com/vim/syntax/css.vim
" Last Change:  2006 Jun 19
" CSS2 by Nikolai Weibull
" Full CSS2, HTML4 support by Yeti
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't have that problem. This is the header of my syntax file:

```
" Vim syntax file
" Language: Cascading Style Sheets
" Maintainer:   Claudio Fleiner <claudio@fleiner.com>
" URL:      http://www.fleiner.com/vim/syntax/css.vim
" Last Change:  2007 Nov 06
" CSS2 by Nikolai Weibull
" Full CSS2, HTML4 support by Yeti
```

The relevant line of the syntax file, is this:

```
syn match cssClassName "\.[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_-]\+"
```

Comment: That URL seems to be referreing to the 2006 Jun 19 version. But changing that line fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: Where did you get that syntax file btw?

Comment: It's the version of vim in Debian unstable, 7.2.025-1. In the vim-runtime package.

Answer (score 1):

What version of vim are you using?

My css.vim is

```
" Vim syntax file
" Language: Cascading Style Sheets
" Maintainer:   Claudio Fleiner <claudio@fleiner.com>
" URL:      http://www.fleiner.com/vim/syntax/css.vim
" Last Change:  2005 Nov 23
" CSS2 by Nikolai Weibull
" Full CSS2, HTML4 support by Yeti
```

as shipped with vim 7.0, and it does not expose the behaviour you described.

Comment: same problem (vim 7.1.138, Ubuntu)

" Vim syntax file
" Language:     Cascading Style Sheets
" Maintainer:   Claudio Fleiner <claudio@fleiner.com>
" URL:          http://www.fleiner.com/vim/syntax/css.vim
" Last Change:  2006 Jun 19
" CSS2 by Nikolai Weibull
" Full CSS2, HTML4 support by Yeti